# Meteor/Iron Router - Create a group of pages

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Is there a way to create classes or groups of pages which I can then apply rules to wholesale?

For example, I have a bit of code that does a forced login, as many pages required a logged in user. However, there are also non-logged in pages.

So, I have something like this:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(onBeforeActions.loginRequired, { except: ['home', 'about'] });
```

to force the login for all except a few pages.

However, as I add pages I'd like to be able to dump them in to buckets, such as "public" or "logged_in", then do something like:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(onBeforeActions.loginRequired, { except: ['public'] });
```

Beyond just applying things like this, I'd also like to do things like apply one layout to all pages of a certain bucket, etc. Anything I can do to group things and cut down on listing every type of page individually.

Is there a way to do something similar to this? I tried to look at the documentation, but nothing immediately jumped out like this.

Thanks.

Comment: Define an array of objects for the pages, with a "group", then iterate through it and call Router.X?

Comment: I thought about that approach and it is valid. What would be an ideal solution for me would be if I could define something kind of like tags that I could then tag routes/pages with. Ex., I might take a page as being "public" and "layout_a", while another would be "public" and "layout_b". The array method would still work, but could get a bit inelegant, especially on a larger project. It'd also move the declaration away from the rest of the route.